# How to avoid error "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double"

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am working with a data frame looking like this:

```
 P   Q1  Q2  G
  1   1   4    1
  2   2   3    2
  3   1   1    3
...
```

This is data from questioning people (P). There were 2 questions with answers from 1-4. G tells me which of 3 groups (e.g. male (1), female (2), child (3)) people belong to.

I now want to draw boxplots in one diagram for each question (next to each other), split apart into 2 subgroups (male, female or child). So there should be 2 groups of boxplots where each group consist of 2 boxplots. All are drawn in one plot.

To do so I used this code:

```
prepdata <- select(mydata,P,G,Q1,Q2) %>% gather(key='Question_num', value='answer', -c(P,G))
   prepdata$G[prepdata$G == 3] <- 2 
prepdata <- prepdata %>% drop_na()

prepdata <- filter(prepdata, (G== 1 | G== 2)) # this is because there are also other Groups in my data which I want to get rid of for this purpose
#prepdata$answer<-unlist(prepdata$answer)

ggplot(prepdata,aes(x=Question_num,y=answer,fill=G))+
  stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar',width=0.8)+
  geom_boxplot(fill='#A4A4A4',width=0.8)
```

I get the error message mentioned in the title. Where is my mistake? I unfortunately can't share the data but it is imported from spss.

Comment: I don't know which of your variables it is, since I can't reproduce the problem, but you can try using `unclass()` or `as.double()` on the variables you feed into the `aes()` function.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).